# how to update jenkins job and run it immediately?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, dsl, jenkins-job-dsl

Hi fellows Jenkin Users,

in short: Is it possible to update a job and run it immediately after the update with the new parameter values applied?

Why do I ask that?
I'm currently starting to work on an existing jenkins pipeline which has a bug. There is one job that scans some folders and starts the second job in another pipeline with the new folders as parameter. When I update the job and start it immediately after, the parameter of the new job is not updated.

So in the `scan.goovy` I have code like:

```
// creates or updates a pipeline job
pipelineJob("secondJob") {
    stringParam('Folders', folders,'New folders')
    ...
}
// start job
queue("secondJob")
```

For now I split the `scan.groovy` file in two file. One script `scan_folder.groovy` that scans the folders and another groovy script `start_new_job.groovy` that starts the second job because the update is only applied when the `scan_folder.groovy` DSL is finished. Then I configure the pipeline to run the two scripts.

Because it would look much cleaner to have only one `*.groovy` file I would prefer to update the job and start it from the same file. Is that somehow possible? Am I missed something like flush() or commit() or what ever?

I would appreciate every helpfull answer, even if you just give me a hint where to find the resources to learn such super power.

Comment: you tried `Poll SCM` option? it will watch for any updates to your repo and start the job if it finds it

Comment: The thing is that these folders are not watched by any SCM they are just a network share.

Comment: i meant your jenkinsfile irself. That must be in some repo right? if the jenkins job just watches that it will kickoff whenever anything changes in the repo

Comment: yep. The jenkinsfile is in a repo but the job does not watches the repo. It just checks it out and uses scripts from there. The job itself is time triggered and checks for changes on the network share and if there is something new it will update another job and should start it.